# Limit Number of Documents Stored by Users in Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If accessing Cloud Firestore client-side, is it there a way to limit the number of documents (per collection) that a user can create?

For example, if we have a Firestore rule to

```
match /users/{userId}/sites/{siteName} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

, this allows an authenticated user to create an unlimited number of documents `/users/<UID>/sites/*`. Is this something that can be limited? We can't use `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/posts)` because `get` only takes documents and not collections as its parameter ([Firebase Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get)) and returns a [Resource object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource).

For any given document, I know we can limit the data set by the user through the `request.resource.data` object. Also, this is easy to do server-side (although it requires two network requests rather than one).

Comment: It's not possible with security rules alone.  You will need to maintain a document that has the count, and use that in your rules.